# ¿Como puedo evitar cambios en una variable vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño inconveniente, como puede hacer para asignar un valor a otra variable y que ese valor quede estatico.
Pongo un ejemplo:

```
//Este valor lo capto de un input
variable1: 'valor inicial',

//variable2 me sirve para guardar mi valor inicial del input
variable2: variable1,
```

Pero tengo un problema ya que como vue es reactivo, al cambiar el valor de la variable1, cambia el valor de la variable2, como puedo hacer para mantener el mismo valor inicial en la variable2?

```
//Este valor lo capto de un input
variable1: 'valor inicial modificado',

//Tambien se me actualiza la variable2
variable2: variable1, //output: valor inicial modificado.
```

Comment: "al cambiar el valor de la variable1 cambia el valor de la variable2", porsupuesto que cambia pero `no` porque vue sea reactivo, mas bien por algo que es muy comun entre los lenguajes y se llama `paso por referencia`, cuando tu asignas a `variable1` otra variable lo que esta haciendo vue es asignar enrealidad el puntero hacia esa misma direccion de memoria, por lo tanto ambas quedan ligadas, de tal forma que si cambias el valor de una tambien cambia el valor de la otra.

Comment: Otro punto importante es que no hay que confundir terminos, *que algo sea estatico no significa que no pueda cambiar*, significa que para poder accederlo hay que usar la clase, pero eso no significa que las propiedades estaticas no se puedan modificar. por lo tanto lo que buscas mas bien es sobre como declarar constantes en vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que por variable estás haciendo referencia a cuando esa variable es un objeto.

En el caso en el que hay una variable que cambia de valor, y es un numero, String, etc, no hay ningún problema en cambiarla de valor sea Vue, React, Angular, etc...

```js
let una = 1;
let otra = una;

una = 5;

console.log(una);
console.log(otra);
```

El problema viene dado por que los objetos en JS al ser almacenados en variables se almacenan por referencia, ello implica que si cambiamos el valor de un atributo en un objeto almacenado en una variable, lo estamos cambiando de su referencia. Por lo tanto, cualquier otra variable que lo almacene verá el valor de ese atributo modificado de la misma manera, aunque no se cambie de forma explícita.

```js
let persona = { nombre: "Pedro" };
let otraPersona = persona;

persona.nombre = "Juan";

console.log(persona);
// No he cambiado explicitamente otraPersona.nombre, sin embargo como otraPersona apunta a la misma referencia que persona, si lo cambio en uno, cambia en otro automáticamente.
console.log(otraPersona);
```

Por tanto, e insisto, independientemente del Framework o librería usados, este hecho es una característica de JS.

¿Como evitarlo?

Muy sencillo, clona el objeto en vez de copiarlo. Tienes varias formas, entre ellas te muestro dos bastante útiles, [Object Assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign) y [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread):

```js
let persona = { nombre: "Pedro" };
// Object Assign
let otraPersona = Object.assign({}, persona);
// Spread Operator
let otraMas = { ...persona };

persona.nombre = "Juan";

console.log(persona);
console.log(otraPersona);
console.log(otraMas);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me a servido el `Object.assign`